# BigQuery Standard SQL RPAD - LPAD inconsistency

Tags: google-bigquery

There seems to be something wrong with RPAD because the response from the query below is true:

SELECT LPAD("hello world", 7) =  RPAD("hello world", 7);

JobId: custom-manifest-113615:bquijob_6cbc14f2_15ce386dbf3

Comment: Indeed, that looks like a bug. According to the docs - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#rpad: _"RPAD("hello world", 7); returns "o world"."_ You should report it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187149%20status:open

Answer (score 3):

I feel like this is not a bug and returns result as expected

Both LPAD/RPAD ("hello world", 7) - return 7 characters of "hello world" and because there are more than 7 characters there - they just returns those without any padding. "hello w" and "hello w"

To see LPAD/RPAD in action - run below

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  LPAD("hello world", 17) as lpad, 
  RPAD("hello world", 17) as rpad, 
  LPAD("hello world", 17) = RPAD("hello world", 17) as compare
```

and

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  LPAD("hello world", 17, ".") as lpad, 
  RPAD("hello world", 17, ".") as rpad, 
  LPAD("hello world", 17, ".") = RPAD("hello world", 17, ".") as compare
```

As of `For example, RPAD("hello world", 7); returns "o world".` from documentation  - I feel it is incorrect!
`Rightness` or `Leftness` is used only to know which direction to fill with pattern!

Note: default value of filled pattern is `blank space`